# ID rose bush please

Tags: roses

hi can anybody identify this rose for me please.

](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3gDE.jpg)[image][image]

Comment: Perhaps my eyesight is failing me but I don't see any thorns.

Comment: She does, they are small but perfectly formed to call make you go ouch